SOFR Curve with Meeting Dates Jump Modelling
When building SOFR curve with meeting dates, i include 1m SOFR Futures and 3m SOFR futures to imply jumps from FOMC meeting dates, but two meeting dates might fall within the same quarterly futures contract period, then it becomes difficult to imply distinct yields for each meeting date. How can you imply the jump from each meeting date separately in this case?

Assumptions or use fed funds 1m futures or fed meeting dated sofr swaps.
